# PayPal buy now button - force auto return (without setting via account)

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to setup a market place where users and buy and sell goods as quickly and simply as possible.

So far I've been able to just dynamically insert the seller's PayPal email into the button and it pays them. Unfortunately though I'm unable to redirect back to my site after this (even when setting the return value for the button) from what I understand this is because the Auto Return value needs to be set via each seller's PayPal backend, however I don't want to have to rely on them doing that.

Is there any way around this? If not, what's the next easiest way to set a system like this up? Extra points for linking to a good tutorial since PayPal's docs can be hard to navigate.

I am confirming payment in our system based on data getting redirect to my site (I know it's a bit risky without IPN but it'll work for now).

Answer (score 1):

The return URL would work properly even without auto return on. However, the buyer has to first click *Return to XXX* to get directed to the auto return page. You can change the return text by setting the variable `cbt`

There are a few ways around this, but it will require you to either move away from Website Payments Standard and towards Express Checkout, or use IPN.

The only other option I can see is giving them a tutorial when setting their account up in your system that has them enable auto return.

Though, without IPN or EC someone could close the browser or tab and you would never have a confirmation.